# How to compose permutations in numpy efficiently?

Tags: python, numpy

I have bijections/permutations on a 3d numpy array given as two 3 tuples of numpy arrays. For example my 3d numpy array could look like this

```
arr = np.array([[[3, 2, 1], [5, 0, 5], [2, 0, 1]],
                [[3, 4, 5], [4, 2, 0], [0, 1, 1]],
                [[2, 0, 5], [1, 5, 1], [0, 5, 1]],
                [[4, 3, 0], [1, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3]],
                [[2, 4, 0], [2, 1, 0], [4, 4, 4]],
                [[4, 3, 2], [2, 4, 2], [5, 5, 5]]])
```

And a permutation on it like this:

```
a, b = ((np.array([5, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
         np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1]),
         np.array([2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0])),
        (np.array([4, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
         np.array([0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2]),
         np.array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1])))
```

I can apply the map by doing `arr[a] = arr[b]`.

My question is: is there an efficient way to compose two of those bijections? For example I want a function `compose` for which the two following statements are equivalent

```
c, d = compose((a, b), (a, b))
arr[c] = arr[d]
```

and

```
arr[a] = arr[b]
arr[a] = arr[b]
```

Comment: can you provide the expected output?

Comment: I assume that `a` and `b` are uniquely defined, i.e., the coordinate 3-tuples in `a` are unique.

Comment: That being said, I'll be surprised if there is a simple answer, since you are overriding the original array after each iteration, so it's not just coordinate (index) dependent operations.

Comment: @QuangHoang. It's not a super complicated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea here is very much like any other resampler: for each destination location, find the corresponding source location. Let's start with a simplified case. Say we have a 1-D array and corresponding indices:

```
arr1 = np.arange(6)
a1 = np.array([3, 4])
b1 = np.array([2, 3])
```

It's much easier to visualize what happens when you make the assignments:

```
arr[a1] = arr[b1] # [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5]
arr[a1] = arr[b1] # [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 5]
```

For a destination index that is the entire array (e.g., `np.arange(arr.size)`), the source index is just the application of the assignment to the destination.

There are a couple of ways of generalizing this to a 3D array. One way would be to make a `(*arr.shapes, arr.ndim)` array containing a meshgrid of all the indices. Another is simply to convert `a` and `b` into [raveled (linear) indices](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html) into the raveled version of `arr`. I recommend going with the latter.

```
a_r = np.ravel_multi_index(a, arr.shape)
b_r = np.ravel_multi_index(b, arr.shape)
```

You can construct a source and destination index pair of the same size as `arr.ravel()`, and set the sources and destinations in it:

```
dest = np.arange(arr.size)
src = np.arange(arr.size)
src[a] = src[b]
```

I wrote out the last assignment "in full", although the first time you can just do `src[a] = b`. You can iterate the last assignment as many times as you want. In your particular example, do it a second time:

```
src[a] = src[b]
```

If you want, you can trim off the elements that are not modified by the assignment:

```
mask = dest != src
dest = dest[mask]
src = src[mask]
```

Finally, you can [unravel the index](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html) back to the original shape:

```
c = np.unravel_index(dest, arr.shape)
d = np.unravel_index(src, arr.shape)
```

If you want to write a function that accepts an arbitrary number of input indices, it might look something like this:

```
def compose(*args, shape=None, sparse=True):
    if shape is None:
        get_max = lambda tup: np.array([arr.max() for arr in tup])
        for a, b in args:
            if shape is None:
                shape = np.maximum(get_max(a), get_max(b))
            else:
                shape = np.maximum(shape, get_max(a))
                shape = np.maximum(shape, get_max(b))
        shape = tuple(shape + 1)

    size = np.prod(shape)
    dest = np.arange(size)
    src = np.arange(size)
    for a, b in args:
        a = np.ravel_multi_index(a, shape)
        b = np.ravel_multi_index(b, shape)
        src[a] = src[b]

    if sparse:
        mask = dest != src
        dest = dest[mask]
        src = src[mask]
    return np.unravel_index(dest, shape), np.unravel_index(src, shape)
```

Comment: While I believe your solution is correct, I somehow still have a tiny doubt in modifying the data in-place. I mean, mathematically, moving an entry to another is just a linear mapping, and composition of those should be again one of those. I'm just not in the right mind to verify all that. +1

Comment: @QuangHoang. I started with a solution that split the arrays into portions where source and destination overlapped, tried iterating through that, only to realize that it was unnecessary. I finally settled on this version after inspecting a lot of test cases with just `np.arange(...)`. It seems to work every time, both conceptually and in practice. I totally feel the part about not being able to verify. I don't really think I can either :)